# Can I let users download my windows 8 metro application from my website?

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store

I wanted to post my new Windows 8.1 metro application to the windows store but I got rejected because I was a minor.  <sup><sup><sup><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sup><sup><sup><sub><sup><sub>(utter bs)</sub></sup></sub></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sup></sup></sup>

I signed up with a new account to try and bypass the age limit (which I find unnessecary) to find out that it costs $65 per year to keep a store account.

I cannot afford this but I want people to be able to use my Windows 8.1 metro application. Can I make it avaliable for download in another location?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264451/will-metro-style-applications-be-able-to-be-installed-outside-the-market-frame

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/09/only-enterprise-and-developers-can-bypass-windows-store-for-metro-apps/

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the .appx file and have users install it via PowerShell?

```
add-appxpackage C:\myapp.appx
```

More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2012/04/03/installing-enterprise-metro-apps-without-using-microsoft-store.aspx

Comment: im not sure because inexperienced users of computers would probably not be able to do this

Comment: You could always create a script / program that did it for them

Comment: how could i go about doing that?

Comment: Create a .ps1 file containing the command, and then have them run the .ps1 file. I'm not exactly sure if it has to be signed (with a certificate or what-not), but it may help run the command automatically. -- more info: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=create+powershell+script